# how to give index of an enum value an get it?

Tags: c++

i have this enum:

```
enum Status { CONTINUE, WON, LOST };
```

i want to give index of one the values (e.g 1 for WON) and get the value (WON).
i searched but i just find the opposite method!!!
i found this code to do but it gives me the index again:

```
int main()
{
enum Status { CONTINUE, WON, LOST };
int myInteger = 1;
Status myValue = (Status)myInteger;
cout << myValue <<endl;//it rerurns 1 !!!
system("PAUSE");
}
```

so what id the syntax of getting a value from an enum?? //i need something like array[1]

Comment: enums will print their numerical value not the name you gave them.

Comment: there is no way to get CONTINUE/WON/LOST without if/case???

Comment: Sounds like you simply need a `std::vector<std::string>` so you can access the index with `v[myInteger]` and get back a string.

Comment: no its a university project that should be done by enum!!!
so i thought there is a way to give/get index<->values in enums!!
so if there is not, i can not understand the usage of enums?!?

Comment: Enums are for selecting from a limited range with meaningful names. Anyway, it's *possible*, albeit ugly, to mostly automate going from value to string and back with Boost.Preprocessor.

Comment: can you explain more or give a link of BoostProecessor ?

Comment: @user3125076, I know there are answers somewhere on SO of how to do it using Boost.PP and how to do it in other ways. I'm sure you can find said answers with some searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enum` type just saves the value not the name

may be you could code like this

```
enum Status { CONTINUE, WON, LOST };
const char* status_names[] = {"CONTINUE", "WON", "LOST"};
int myInteger = 1;
cout << status_names[myInteger] << endl;
```

[here](http://ideone.com/ud0JxM) is the ideone link

Comment: so at last we should use some thing else to get the name :D
but it a good idea to use it! (Y)

Answer (score 3):

C++ "inherited" `enum` from C. It's really little more than a short-hand notation for the traditional way of doing things in C, where your `enum` would have been something like:

```
#define CONTINUE 0
#define WON 1
#define LOST 2
```

`enum` automates assigning successive numbers to the symbols, but not much more than that.

C++11 added `enum class` that creates an enumeration that's more like a normal type, but it still doesn't provide an (automated) way to convert from a numeric representation to the symbol you used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` from the STL.

for instace:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string> 


using namespace std;

int main()
{

    typedef enum { CONTINUE, WON, LOST } status_t;

    map<int, string> Status = {
        {CONTINUE, "CONTINUE"},
        {WON, "WON"},
        {LOST, "LOST"}
    };


    cout << Status[1] << endl;    
    // It's also possible
    cout << Status[CONTINUE] << endl;    



    return 0;
}
```